# How can I call android Activity without startAcitivity(intent)?

Tags: android

In the main page of my android app I've added OptionsMenu.
What i want is when the option "ContactUs" is selected a new Activity called "ContactUs" should get called.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
if (item.getTitle().toString().equals("ContactUs")) {
    ContactUs contact = new ContactUs(Home.this);
}
return true;
}
```

And when the ContactUs activity is opened its layout should be displayed:

```
public class ContactUs extends Activity{
private Context CONTEXT;

public CustomEqualizer(Context c){
    this.CONTEXT = c;
    setContentView(R.layout.contactus);
}
}
```

But the problem is the layout will not be displayed until onCreate method is called.
My question is how can I call ContactUs option from Home without startActivity?

Comment: From your example, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't want to use `startActivity()`…

Comment: There is no reason why not to use `startActivity`. Also you should never instantiate an `Activity` by yourself, instead let the android system do that.

Comment: Try to rephrase your question so that community is able to pin-point your mistake and help you.

Answer (score 4):

`startActivity()` is the only way to start an Activity. The problem you're having is that you're trying to call `setContentView()` in the constructor which won't work anyway since it hasn't gotten the application context yet. You override the `onCreate()` method and call it from there.

-= update =-

You can pass whatever you want between activities by adding it to the Intent's bundle.

Comment: Okay I'll elaborate my ques. I'm doing this because I want to pass one object reference from Home class to ContactUs, which I'll use it there. I want ContactUs to remain an activity but also want to call it from Home.

Comment: I mean I want ContactUs both to be used as an activity as well as called via other class Home.