# "what are the two ways to call an activity in android?"

Tags: android, android-intent

I had an interview and the interviewer asked, "What are the two ways to call another activity from one in android?"
I knew that we can use Intent to go to another activity from one but didn't know second way of calling other activity.

Can anyone please tell me other way, if they know?
Thanks!

Comment: I searched a lot on the internet but couldnt find anything. May be i am searching with wrong keywords. Pls help.

Comment: I would say the answer is implicit and explicit intents. call it by name (explicit) or by action/data/category (implicit)

Comment: @njzk2 i also explained him about intent filter and calling it by class name. But he was still interested in another way of calling an activity.

Comment: there are tons of ways. you can use an alarmmanager with a pendingintent, you can use a notification, you can start a chooser, you can start the activity from a broadcastreceiver ...

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, i agree. I completely forgot about those.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answer was: 1- `startActivity(Intent intent)` method and 2- `startActivityForResult(Intent intent)` method

Comment: But both are methods of intent class. So it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: @RTL The interviewer didn't ask you for two classes, did he/she?

Comment: Actually, these are the methods that *call* `Activity`s. `Intent`s just provide information.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10626427/645270) answer supports _this_ answer.

Comment: Is there any way to make something without method? I'm sure he was trying to get the answer above. 2 different methods are 2 different ways to do something.

Comment: (also, the implementation of startActivity actually calls startActivityForResult).

Comment: @Keyser No he didnt mention classes.

Comment: @Renan May be you are right, i explained him two ways of passing an intent (intent filter and class name) but he still wanted to know another way

Comment: @njzk2 I see, but the interviewers don't usually go so deeply. I prefer to see that he was trying to make a question to get the answer about startActivity and startActivityForResult than another thing, since he is wrong.